# How to get amazon product name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Sorry if this post seems like a duplicate but i cant find a working way to do this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree as et
import time
import random
import csv

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
    'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
}

bucket_list = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/Military-Analogue-Waterproof-Tactical-Minimalist/dp/B0B6C7RMQD/']


def get_product_name(dom):
    try:
        name = dom.xpath('//span[@id="productTitle"]/text()')
        [name.strip() for name in name]
        return name[0]
    except Exception as e:
        name = 'Not Available'
        return None


with open('master_data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['product name', 'url'])

    

for url in bucket_list:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        amazon_dom = et.HTML(str(soup))

       

 product_name = get_product_name(amazon_dom)

       

 time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))

       

 writer.writerow([product_name, url])
        print(product_name, url)
```

i have this code that opens the link and looks for its name and pastes it into a csv file but it pastes nothing. how can i fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using the [Amazon Selling Partner API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/)?

Comment: i am trying to do it without a sellers account

Comment: As to the question, I think Mihnea-Octavian Manolache gives a good answer, but nevertheless your code could be improved in several areas. 1) Never index anything when you're not sure it won't throw IndexError (so add `if name` before `return name[0]`, btw in line before you have a list comprehension executing but not saving itself to any variable - probably not what you intended).

Comment: 2) Never do `except Exception` because you'll catch even KeyboardInterrupt and won't be able to debug your scripts. 3) In your except clause you're saving value to a local variable `name` that you won't be able to access out of the function's scope. 4) You're returning `None` if exception happens, but then doesn't acknowledge this in the calling code and use it as it returned a string. Either return an empty string in case of exception or test for `None` in the calling code.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon is a heavily dynamic website; meaning it loads programatically (using JS). Simply using requests is usually not enough to scrape Amazon. So the reason you don't get any result is probably because your `response` doesn't actually have any `dom.xpath('//span[@id="productTitle"]/text()')`.

If you want to scrape Amazon, consider using Selenium.

First things first, in order to render JavaScript, you need to use an actual browser. Since you're script is in Python, I recommend you to install [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and use it with an HTML parser (like BeautifulSoup) in order to extract your data. Here is an implementation example:

```py
from cmath import exp
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

BUCKET_LIST = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/Military-Analogue-Waterproof-Tactical-Minimalist/dp/B0B6C7RMQD/']

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5000)

titles = []
for url in BUCKET_LIST:
    driver.get(url)
    title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#productTitle')))
    titles.append(title.text)

driver.quit()

print(titles)
```

But then you also have to take into consideration the fact that Amazon takes a lot of measures to prevent scraping.